# Why is the upgrade to GarageBand free but iPhoto requires a paid upgrade (after migrating from Snow Leopard to Mavericks)?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac-appstore, photos.app, ilife

GarageBand and iPhoto are both [iLife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILife) applications that came with Snow Leopard when I originally got my iMac. I have recently upgraded to Mavericks and both apps were in need of an update.

So why is it one happily upgrades for free yet the other is asking me to pay for it in the app store?

This is inconsistent to say the least.

Comment: Apple does not share publicly they business decisions and the motivations behind it.

Comment: iPhoto appears to be free in new versions (at least since Yosemite)